# Windows won't boot without linux usb( I enter grub rescue)

Tags: windows, grub, parrot-os

I tried to install parrot os on my usb. I succeded, but my laptop won't boot into windows without usb on which linux is installed. It says: unkown device:(some numbers), unkown file system. When my usb is in the laptop, I get dual boot option, then I can boot into windows. I tried troubleshoot with fixmbr, fixboot and rebuildbcd. Nothing worked.
It didn't work with extrernal usb repair
Os:Windows 11

Os 2: Parrot os 5

Comment: Take out usb stick.  [Pop in windows 11 boot media and repair](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+11+media+repair+boot).

Comment: I already tried without usb repair stick, i tried from the windows itself. Do I explicitly need  usb repair stick?

Comment: Yes, use the windows media creation tool and make one.

Comment: I just did and tried it didn't work

Comment: It didn't work with usb repair

Comment: If your machine has UEFI firmware instead of BIOS, you probably still have a UEFI boot entry of Windows Boot Manager that allows you to boot to Windows anyway. It's just you need to find the key that can get you to the UEFI boot menu. The problem here is probably that this parrot os installer / you decided to use Windows EFI system partition instead of creating its own. You can show Disk Management from Windows and/or `fdisk -l` from Linux for us to confirm. `efibootmgr` helps too.

Comment: This is to complicated, will reintsalling windows solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe, though there's still a chance that the grub UEFI boot entry will linger (and even, remain as the first in the boot order). If my guess is correct, it's not that any part of Windows has been corrupted. The real solution is that you should ditch the entry with `efibootmgr` (and optionally remove the grub EFI executable from the Windows ESP).